# Paged homepage - requirements?

Tags: loop, pagination

I've got the following loop in index.php file:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$post_per_page = 30;
$do_not_show_stickies = 1;

$args=array(
    'post_type' => array ('portfolio'),
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => $do_not_show_stickies
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( have_posts() ) : 
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
             //Do some stuff...
```

It works perfect. It displays 30 posts but how do I access second page?

I tried: 
- http://example.com/?paged=2 (server's 404 error)
- http://example.com/page/2 (redirects to homepage and removes `/page/2` part)
- `<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>` (returns nothing)

I have default permalinks. What am I doing wrong? How do I access second page of posts?

Comment: have you tried `if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :` instead of `if( have_posts() ) :`

Comment: @amit Yes, it didn't help and didn't change anything. That `if statement` was returning true all the time and `while` takes posts from correct loop.

Comment: hey, `http://example.com/portfolio/?paged=2` works ?

Comment: @amit Nope. 404. I think that my loop is just wrong and I'll start from scratch (but first read more about loops).

Answer (score 0):

If you put the following after the while loop, does it link to anything?

```
<?php next_posts_link('&laquo; previous posts');
    if (get_next_posts_link() && get_previous_posts_link())
        echo ' | ';
    previous_posts_link('next posts &raquo;');
?>
```

Comment: It links to exactly this (only previous link shows up): `http://example.com/?paged=2` But when I enter that link I'm redirected to `http://example.com/`. I have no redirection plugins and clean .htaccess on this server.

Comment: I know why it was redirecting me to homepage. Because 404.php has redirect. And the content of that paged=2 link is: `404 Not Found - http://example.com/?paged=2`. So, my question should be "why is it returning 404?"

Comment: Are the two URL fields in general settings correct?

Comment: Yes, it's fresh installation of WordPress. I already tried different permalinks structures without luck. It's always `404 - not found` when I enter second page. Can it be something wrong with that loop in index.php perhaps? It gives me this notice: `Undefined property: WP_Query::$post` for instance.

Comment: EDIT: resolved this error (it was because of some other undefined variable as argument) but pagination error still remains.

Comment: Surprisingly pagination WORKS when I move the same exact code to my-template.php and use it as page template. I can use `?paged=2` without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using index.php as it also gets used for other archives should the more specific templates not exist. For the frontpage, use frontpage.php or home.php

Also if you're only displaying your custom query, I'd advise you use the `pre_get_posts` hook instead of throwing away the main query and presenting your own. This will let you use the main loop and sidestep the entire pagination issue

edit: notice you have `if(have_posts)`, this checks if the main query has posts, not if your custom query has posts. Change it to `$wp_query->have_posts` instead

Comment: Neither home.php nor front-page.php work but my-template.php works (as page template). I move current (main) query to `$temp` but it seems this might be problematic.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by moving the main query to `$temp`, you don't 'move' the main query

Comment: It's like `$temp = $wp_query; $wp_query = null;` and then back after my one is finished.

Comment: that's unnecessary though, just do wp_reset_postdata when you're finished with your WP_Query object, you should never have to do that with $wp_query, there's no need for it, and WP_Query doesn't modify $wp_query anyway, it modifies $post

Comment: **Read this:** http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012